# Merge a data in db-table with new data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, dbcontext

I'm new to Entity framework. I have an application that reads data from xml and stores it in database.

Reading and inserting of the data is a daily job.

In Entity Framework, how can I merge the new data if there is new data in the xml with the old data in the same table?

This code inserts new data when its called, which makes allot of duplicate entities. And I don't want that the data stored in db to be changed.

```
public void MyCustomTypes(string Xml)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(Xml);
    List<Category> allCateogries = new List<Category>();

    var db = new MyContext();

    var caq1 = xDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.Contains("FaceAdd")).Elements().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName.Contains("Buildingtype")).Select(v=>v.Value).Distinct().ToList();

    foreach (var x in caq1)
    {
        Category category = new Category
               {
                   Name = x.ToString(),
                   NrOfFaceAdds= getNr(x.ToString(), xDoc)
               };
        allCateogries.Add(category);                  
    }

    db.Categories.AddRange(allCateogries);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Fetch your old data from the DB and use Union to merge the lists together: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341731.aspx Then insert the values.

Comment: Check update for my answer please

Answer (score 1):

First get all the records from the DB, then using this remove the duplicate in the new list by checking if the `Name` and `NrOfFaceAdds` is not already in the DB.

```
var oldCategories =  db.Categories.ToList();
var filteredCategories = allCateogries.Where(i => !oldCategories.Any(c => c.Name == i.Name) && !oldCategories.Any( c=> c.NrOfFaceAdds == i.NrOfFaceAdds));     

db.Categories.AddRange(filteredCategories );
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Oops, Except is the way to go. I confused something. Thanks :)

Comment: `.Except()` will check objects by their hashcodes and will not remove duplicates because their hascodes are different

Comment: @Fabjan yes thanks for pointing it out, I found it while testing too. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's refactor your code a little with LINQ first:

```
public void MyCustomTypes(string Xml)
{
    XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(Xml);
    var db = new MyContext();

    var caq1 = xDoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName.Contains("FaceAdd")).Elements().Where(n => n.Name.LocalName.Contains("Buildingtype")).Select(v=>v.Value).Distinct().ToList();

    List<Category> allCateogries = caq1.Select(x => 
        new Category
        {
             Name = x.ToString(),
             NrOfFaceAdds= getNr(x.ToString(), xDoc)
        }).ToList();

    // now we need to add only unique items from this list to database 
    // one way to solve this problem is to create custom hashset and check if object's Name is there
    // this is also very fast as HashSet<T> lookup is almost O(1)

    HashSet<string> catNames = new HashSet<string>(db.Categories.Select(c => c.Name));

    db.Categories.AddRange(allCateogries.Where(c => !catNames.Contains(c.Name)));
}
```

Another way is to use `.Except()` method with custom IEqualityComparer. We need to do it because default comparer will check object hashcodes and not properties.

```
public class MyEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Category>
{
    public bool Equals(Category x, Category y)
    {
        return x.Name == y.Name;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Category obj)
    {
        return obj.Name;
    }
}
```

Then we can do :

```
db.Categories.AddRange(allCateogries.Except(db.Categories, new MyEqualityComparer()));
```